# Serverless define a Dynamodb that has GlobalSecondaryIndexes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless, dynamodb-queries

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
I've gone back and forwards the documentation. seems like it should be a simple thing but can't figure out why it does not let me

An error occurred: documentsTable - One or more parameter values were invalid: Some index key attributes are not defined in AttributeDefinitions. Keys: [UserId], AttributeDefinitions: [userId, id] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: K28DP2ST778DAN7CP1MV4BDKM3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null).

```
    documentsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: UserId
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: userIdIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: UserId
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.env}-${self:custom.prefix}-${self:custom.documentDynamoTable2}
```

then ofcourse I will have a query like this

```
query(
            {
                TableName: documentTable,
                IndexName: 'userIdIndex',
                KeyConditionExpression: '#userId = :userId',
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ':userId': aUserId
                },
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#userId": "userId"
                },
                Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
            }
        ).promise();
```

error:

```
{
    "errorType": "ValidationException",
    "errorMessage": "Query condition missed key schema element: id",
    "code": "ValidationException",
    "message": "Query condition missed key schema element: id",
    "time": "2021-03-03T22:59:22.298Z",
    "requestId": "24B4KVLCT9PTIDPPN06ITUTG0JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 28.89477589112033,
    "stack": [
        "ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id",
..........
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are defining an attribute named `userId` (lowercase u) and later referring to `UserId` (uppercase U).

You want this

```
documentsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId      // <--- CHANGE HERE
            KeyType: HASH 
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: userIdIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: userId  // <--- CHANGE HERE
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.env}-${self:custom.prefix}-${self:custom.documentDynamoTable2}
```

Comment: thank you @Seth you where right but now thing if I done it right, as running the query and getting an error that i need to pass the Id, but I want to get all object by userId.

Comment: Why would one create a GSI that has the same PK as the base table?

Comment: @Kirk makes a good point, which makes me wonder if there is some confusion about DynamoDB indexes.  

DynamoDB indexes are *not* the same thing as their RDBMS counterparts.  There is no need to create a secondary index in DynamoDB that matches the primary key in your base table, it's redundant.  Indexes in DDB are meant to support additional access patterns.  For example, your base table is set up to fetch users by ID.  If you wanted to fetch users by some other attribute (e.g. email), you could make an index with PK set to email.